# troubleshooting a SQL code for cohort analysis

Tags: sql

Having a problem with a code I wrote to perform a cohort analysis for repeat purchases. Can someone help me? My code was able to identify repeat purchases and assigning cohort for the most part BUT it is unable to assign a proper label for the last purchase of that customer. It's being labeled as "new to brand" highlighted in red here. It should be labeled as "0-15 days." Any suggestion? I realized that my code doesn't differentiate between cases when this is the user's first purchase or their final one. I'm not sure how to troubleshoot it. Any suggestion appreciated. Code and pic attached.

OLD RESULT: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZvpy.png

NEW RESULT WITH NEW CODE: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUndb.png

```
SELECT DISTINCT "T1"."amazon-order-id", 
"T1"."BRAND",
"T1"."buyer-email", 
"T1"."purchase-date", 
MIN("T2"."purchase-date") AS "Next Purchase Date",
MAX("T2"."purchase-date") AS "Last Purchase Date",
DATEDIFF(Day,"T1"."purchase-date", MIN("T2"."purchase-date")) AS "Days Difference",
CASE
WHEN "Days Difference" < 15 THEN '0-15 days'
WHEN "Days Difference" < 30 THEN '15-30 days'
WHEN "Days Difference" < 45 THEN '30-45 days'
WHEN "Days Difference" < 60 THEN '45-60 days'
WHEN "Days Difference" > 60 THEN '60+ days'
WHEN "T1"."purchase-date" = "Next Purchase Date" THEN 'NTB'
END "Cohort",
sum("T1"."shipped-quantity") AS "Units Sold", 
sum("T1"."item-price") AS "Sales"
    
FROM "DATA_WAREHOUSE"."PUBLIC"."AMAZON_FULFILLED_SHIPMENT_REPORT" AS T1
LEFT JOIN
    "DATA_WAREHOUSE"."PUBLIC"."AMAZON_FULFILLED_SHIPMENT_REPORT" AS T2
    ON "T1"."buyer-email" = "T2"."buyer-email"
    AND "T2"."purchase-date" > "T1"."purchase-date"
GROUP BY "T1"."amazon-order-id", 
"T1"."buyer-email", 
"T1"."BRAND",
"T1"."purchase-date"
ORDER BY 
"T1"."BRAND",
"T1"."buyer-email", 
"T1"."purchase-date",
"T1"."amazon-order-id"
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (I'd expect an error for that query.)

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT combined with GROUP BY raises many eyebrows.

Comment: Your `CASE WHEN` does not correctly cover "Days Difference"=60.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your case statement. You are Left Joining T2 with purchases GREATER than the T1 Purchase Date, which for the last purchase would mean the T2 table would not return any rows.

To get Latest purchases to be labeled in the 0-15 day category, you would need to include an "Is Null" criteria or add a coalesce statement into your DATEDIFF if MIN(T2.Purchase_Date) is null to pull the T1 date.

Edit:
Something like this may work if you only have one purchase per date. You may not need the second left join to get the Last Purchase Date if you don't need that field in the query:

```
SELECT "T1"."amazon-order-id"
    ,"T1"."BRAND"
    ,"T1"."buyer-email"
    ,"T1"."purchase-date"
    ,"T2"."purchase-date" AS "Next Purchase Date"
    ,"T3"."purchase-date" AS "Last Purchase Date"
    ,DATEDIFF(Day, "T1"."purchase-date", "T2"."purchase-date") AS "Days Difference"
    ,CASE 
        WHEN LAG("T1"."purchase-date") OVER (
                PARTITION BY "T1"."buyer-email" ORDER BY "T1"."purchase-date"
                ) IS NULL
            THEN 'NTB'
        WHEN "T2"."purchase-date" IS NULL
            THEN 'Last_Purchase'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(Day, "T1"."purchase-date", "T2"."purchase-date") < 15
            THEN '0-15 days'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(Day, "T1"."purchase-date", "T2"."purchase-date") < 30
            THEN '15-30 days'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(Day, "T1"."purchase-date", "T2"."purchase-date") < 45
            THEN '30-45 days'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(Day, "T1"."purchase-date", "T2"."purchase-date") < 60
            THEN '45-60 days'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(Day, "T1"."purchase-date", "T2"."purchase-date") > 60
            THEN '60+ days'
        END "Cohort"
    ,"T1"."shipped-quantity" AS "Units Sold"
    ,"T1"."item-price" AS "Sales"
FROM "DATA_WAREHOUSE"."PUBLIC"."AMAZON_FULFILLED_SHIPMENT_REPORT" AS T1
LEFT JOIN "DATA_WAREHOUSE"."PUBLIC"."AMAZON_FULFILLED_SHIPMENT_REPORT" AS T2 ON "T1"."buyer-email" = "T2"."buyer-email"
    AND "T2"."purchase-date" = (
        SELECT Min(T2E."purchase-date")
        FROM "DATA_WAREHOUSE"."PUBLIC"."AMAZON_FULFILLED_SHIPMENT_REPORT" AS T2E
        WHERE "T1"."buyer-email" = T2E ."buyer-email"
                                and "T1"."purchase-DATE" < "T2E"."purchase-DATE")
LEFT JOIN
    "DATA_WAREHOUSE"."PUBLIC"."AMAZON_FULFILLED_SHIPMENT_REPORT" AS T3
    ON "T1"."buyer-email" = "T3"."buyer-email"
    AND "T3"."purchase-DATE" = (select max(T2E."purchase-DATE") 
                                from "DATA_WAREHOUSE"."PUBLIC"."AMAZON_FULFILLED_SHIPMENT_REPORT" AS T2E 
                                where "T1"."buyer-email"=T2E."buyer-email"
            AND "T1"."purchase-date" < "T2E"."purchase-date"
        )
ORDER BY "T1"."BRAND"
    ,"T1"."buyer-email"
    ,"T1"."purchase-date"
    ,"T1"."amazon-order-id"
```

In SQL Server, I would have normally just done this with a windows function within an Outer/Cross Apply to reduce the number of times referencing the DATEDIFF, but it's not available in snowflake AFAIK.

Comment: Was adjusting the code and missed a WHEN "" IS NULL THEN "New To Brand" statement. Still not able to figure out how to assign a category for the last purchase date. The problem is the first purchase date is being compared to the second purchase date when it should be categorized as "New To Brand" or "First Purchase"

Comment: You shouldn't be getting NTB for that record. It should return NULL because you are joining T2 to only return purchases greater than the T1 purchase date, not equal to. Identify the difference between NTB and Latest Purchase from existing customers, you will need to either use a windows function like LAG() or join the table again to check for previous purchases. What DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using snowflake. Do you have any idea in mind? I'm not well versed in SQL (clearly). Should I rethink my LEFT JOIN and do something different?

Comment: I've edited to include a sample query

Comment: Thank you for the sample query. It looks like Snowflake doesn't support multiple subqueries. I get this error: SQL compilation error: Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated

Comment: Maybe there is an issue with the subquery criteria or quotes. you might check the field names and tables and syntax.

Comment: I've tried to edit the query to remove some strange spacing that was in there.

Comment: This works wonderfully. I bow down to you. Is there a way to label "Last Purchase" to the months they fall on? I'm interested see when their last purchase is. https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUndb.png

Comment: You can Concatenate using CONCAT or double pipe || to add the Month name using the MONTHNAME function with the "Last Purchase" value. Please mark this as the answer if this solved your issue.